# Why thenCombine result doesn't complete exceptionally if returning a failed stage?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future, completion-stage

The following code snippet, which invokes [thenCombine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCombine(java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage,java.util.function.BiFunction)), does not set an exception at [whenComplete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#whenComplete(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) (it prints `No exception`):

```
    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)
    .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true),
        (x,y) -> {
        return CompletableFuture.failedStage(new RuntimeException());
    })
    .whenComplete( (myVal, myEx) -> {
      if (myEx == null) {
         System.out.println("No exception");
      } else {
         System.out.println("There was an exception");
      }
    });
```

However, the similar code below, which invokes [thenCompose](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose(java.util.function.Function)), does set an exception:

```
    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true)
    .thenCompose(
        x -> {
          return CompletableFuture.failedStage(new RuntimeException());
        })
    .whenComplete( (myVal, myEx) -> {
      if (myEx == null) {
        System.out.println("No exception");
      } else {
        System.out.println("There was an exception");
      }
    });
```

Why is `thenCombine` returning a normally-completed `CompletionStage` when its BiFunction is actually returning a failed stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example `CompletableFuture.failedStage(new RuntimeException())` *is* the result. The `CompletableFuture` returned by `thenCombine` is completed with `CompletableFuture.failedStage(new RuntimeException())`.

It gets clearer when you don't chain the calls:

```java
CompletableFuture<Boolean> first = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
CompletableFuture<Boolean> second = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
        
CompletableFuture<CompletionStage<?>> yourQuestion =
        first.thenCombine(second, (x, y) ->
                CompletableFuture.failedStage(new RuntimeException()));
```

For your second example you need to read the documentation of `thenCompose` carefully:

> Returns a new CompletionStage that is completed with the same value as the CompletionStage returned by the given function.

In the function for `thenCompose` you return a failed `CompletableFuture` and *its result* is used as the result for the `CompletableFuture` returned by `thenCompose`: a `RuntimeException`.